# Regexp repetition defined by backreference

Tags: ruby, regex

In Ruby (PCRE), is it possible to use a backreference to a captured decimal value to define a repetition length?

```
/^(\d+),.{\1}/.match('4,abcdefgh') # Should match '4,abcd'
```

The above code just returns `nil` (finds no matches).

Comment: Regexes don't get that meta.

Comment: Do it programmatically afterwards.

Comment: This may be an XY-question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String#to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-to_i), which gives you the number at the start:

```
str = '4,abcdefgh'
str.match(/^(\d+),.{#{str.to_i}}/) # => #<MatchData "4,abcd" 1:"4">
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that with regular expressions. If the range of decimal values however is limited, you could build a regular expression containing all possible combinations, something like:

```
'1abcde2abcde3abcde4abcde'.scan(/1.{1}|2.{2}|3.{3}|4.{4}/)
#=> ["1a", "2ab", "3abc", "4abcd"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use two regular expressions:

```
str = '4,abcdefgh'

str =~ /\A(\d+,)/
str[0,$1.size+$1.to_i]
  #=> "4,abcd"
```